# Select dotenv when run and deploy functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables, firebase-tools

I have these files in my projetct:

[image]

And I am following what this documentation says, but these commands are not working:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/config-env?hl=pt-br

```
$ firebase use dev
$ firebase deploy --only functions
i functions: Loaded environment variables from .env, .env.dev.
# Deploys functions with following user-defined environment variables:
#   PLANET=Earth
#   AUDIENCE=Dev Humans

$ firebase use prod
$ firebase deploy --only functions
i functions: Loaded environment variables from .env, .env.prod.
# Deploys functions with following user-defined environment variables:
#   PLANET=Earth
#   AUDIENCE=Prod Humans
```

I am receiving this error:
`Error: Invalid project selection, please verify project dev exists and you have access.` 
But .env.dev is not a project, is the file that I want the program considers to env. How to do that without having to insert all the env in formation in .env?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is showing you commands to run when you have two different projects to work with.  It assumes that you have already created those projects and they have aliases called "dev" and "prod".  You probably didn't create those aliases.  You should [follow the instructions on creating aliases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#project_aliases) for your projects before running `firebase use`.